# Does Googlebot (and/or search engines) index a forwarded page?

Tags: search-engines, https, search-engine-indexing, googlebot

Let's say I have `example.com` domain, and I force the user to use the HTTPS over HTTP.

The question is as browsers just accept and load the forwarded/new page (when the request for `http://example.com` -> `https://example.com`), does the Googlebot (or other search engines) accept the forwarded page and index the new page and just ignore the old page?

In other word, does search engines accept HTTPS beside the HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new page will be indexed and the old page will be removed from the index, assuming the content of both page is the same and that one has not left a canonical URL to the HTTP URL in the HTTPS version.

Yes, search engines are fine with HTTPS.

Comment: thanks buddy, now I have peace in my mind about https, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 301 header when redirecting the page. This way you're telling Google that the page has moved and it will index it.

Google has recently announced that it [will offer a boost to SSL websites](http://searchengineland.com/google-starts-giving-ranking-boost-secure-httpsssl-sites-199446).